# Database Table Layout

Tags: database-design

In setting up a MySQL database, consider that I have a table of products (tblCar) named:

- Coupe
- Sedan
- Mini-van
- Truck

And a list of (1980's) accessories:

- Moon roof
- Chrome wheels
- Window Tint

And a list of of options:

- paint color
- interior finish
- interior color
- Blu-Ray player in-dash

Now, let's setup some ground rules:

- Coupe can choose from any accessory or option
- Sedan can choose from any accessory but provides no Blu-Ray option
- Mini-van has window tint as an accessory and can choose from all options
- Truck only has chrome wheels, tint accessories and only paint options

I need a **tblCar** setup, that much is clear. But how do I manage a table of **tblAccessories** and **tblOptions** without duplicating the line items themselves. Let's pretend that I only want description information for accessories and options and not prices as those would surely be different for the car they were installed in.

Would this be a case for **tblAccessoriesHelper** that holds a list of values of *carID* and *accessoryID* where the two should meet or this there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have junction tables, that join the two together

```
tblCar
tblAccessories
tblOptions 
tblCarAccessories
tblCarOptions
```

There is another naming convention that uses the prefix "jct" if you are naming tables using "tbl".  I would have named the tables

```
Car
Accessory
Options
CarAccessory
CarOptions
```

(name tables using the singular form, but "options" is special, because "option" could be a reserved/special word in some DBMS)